# Change default program output colors on mac terminal

Tags: macos, colors, terminal, osx-lion, background-color

I don't know if this is the right place to post this question, but here goes:

I recently (less than a year ago) made the switch to a mac from my ubuntu setup. One of the first things I changed was terminal.app's background color and opacity. In my old setup, it was a semi-transparent, black window, which I would put on top of other windows, so I could see the code on it, as well as look through it at the window under it. terminal.app on my mac looks like this now. This is great… except when I have to use programs like sphinx or look at man pages.

Some programs have outputs in black font; man pages have entries in black font. Since the background of my terminal.app is also black, this font is rendered almost invisible (seen in the two screenshots below):

[image: Invisible font in terminal.app]

[image: Highlighting the invisible font in terminal.app]

Is there any way that I can tell terminal.app to display all black text as some other color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that in Terminal's Preferences ?
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was futzing around with the `Basic` profile and didn't know about the others. Geez, sometimes, I think I'm just blind :P

Comment: Specifically, change the “Bold text” color from black to something lighter. The black man-page text is bold.